# How to hide bottom system bar in android tablet

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-widget, android-permissions

I am developing an application for tablet only, where the requirement is to run the app on the full screen of the tablet.

For this I have used following code in my main activity:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This code snippet only removes the title bar and action bar. But in tablets, there is a bottom system bar (having home and back button). I also want to remove or hide this system bar too.

I have searched but there is only following solution:

1. There is no API to remove or hide the system bar.
2. You can use some android app to hide system bar. (for example:
   surelock, hidebar, etc)

My question is :

1. **Is it really not possible in android?**
2. **Above available app (i.e surelock, hide bar, etc) also hiding bar.
   It means they are using something to do so. Can be use this
   something in our app so the user will not require to download these
   app seperatly.**

Please guide me.

I know this is not a good idea. But My app is only for tablet having Android 4.0 or greater and that **tablet will run only this single app so we do not need to go back and use home button.** That's why my requirement is to use the app in full screen.

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea to hide system bar, because this is the place where user actually can control the behaviour of your app - back button / home button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605313/931982

Answer (score 9):

If you have root access you can use this code other wise it is not allowed

```
try{
    //REQUIRES ROOT
    Build.VERSION_CODES vc = new Build.VERSION_CODES();
    Build.VERSION vr = new Build.VERSION();
    String ProcID = "79"; //HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

    //v.RELEASE  //4.0.3
    if(vr.SDK_INT >= vc.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
        ProcID = "42"; //ICS AND NEWER
    }



    //REQUIRES ROOT
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity "+ ProcID +" s16 com.android.systemui"}); //WAS 79
    proc.waitFor();

}catch(Exception ex){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454528/hide-system-bar-in-jelly-bean-tablet-rooted)

Comment: Hi, answer totally works fine. But How can I show the bar again can you help please?

Answer (score 8):

From Android API 4.0 and later you can use the following code to hide the bottom system bar.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible unless you've root access. Alternatively, you can create a **`launcher application`**.

Otherwise it will be beyond the scope of your Application to Hide System/Navigation bar.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is only possible if you have either the root access or you have created any launcher application." ?

Comment: Android is an operating system based on Linux. So as in Linux, android also have two types of users: 1. Super/root user 2. Normal user. Now if you gain the root user access or you create any application as Go Launcher or something like that then only you can do what you want

Comment: How can I have root access to my app? And how it is possible if I have root access to hide system bar?

Comment: Please read this completely: http://www.androidcentral.com/root and hiding a system bar, I guess you need to write some commands for it, I have never done that before.

Comment: Before rooting your device, please be sure that you really have a good reason.

Comment: @Shrikant Can you post Code to hide bottom bar for launcher application. I have the same Problem and my application is launcher

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I managed to get the System Bar to hide and appear in a 4.2 device using:

To Hide:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

Or use 79 instead of 42 for API less than 14. You may also need to include the SET_DEBUG_APP permission, in which case you need to have the application signed with the system key or installed in the /system/app/ directory.

To Show:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
```

Alternatively some people have used the -a (instead of -n) option, though this was causing an error on my device:

Error: Not found; no service started.