# Start Google Maps activity in full screen (and hide the system UI)

Tags: android, google-maps

My app hides the system UI and hence cant see the soft buttons on Nexus 5. I have the following code to hide the soft buttons

```
  public void hideSystemUI() {
    View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

So far so good. My app also starts an intent to open up the maps, as follows

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=85041";  
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
        "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_INTENT_MAPS);
hideSystemUI();
```

As you can see the last line of second snippet above calls the first snippet to hide the system UI (soft buttons). But when maps opens up, I still see the soft buttons (attached the screen shot of the same).

How can I hide the system UI (soft buttons on nexus 5) when an intent opens up another application

[image: How to hide the 3 soft buttons at the bottom of the picture]

Comment: You need to set the Flags of the Intent to hide the UI... your method only hides for the current Activity

Comment: Which particular flags on Intent should I set? I cannot find it from API docs (has about 50 flags)

Comment: Before I answer that, I believe the flags may not be supported by all applications. (For example, the MapsActivity may not know how to handle that)

Comment: visit this if you have to hide that 3 `Button` but keep in mind you have require Api 19. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057096/how-to-hide-bottom-system-bar-in-android-tablet

Comment: @Ironman That only helps for the current activity window in the current app... OP is opening Google Maps

Comment: @cricket_007: what are those flags anyway

Comment: Yeah  I looked at the intent documentation and I don't think I was right.