# Enabling KioskMode in Android 4.4.2 with Root

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, kiosk-mode

I was able to enable kiosk mode in pre-KitKat-releases by killing the `com.android.systemui` process. Anyhow, this seems not to work in KitKat-releases: After killing the process the whole screen got stuck and I am not able to press any buttons.

After inspecting similar apps from the Play Store I saw recent updates providing a compatibility for KitKat (e.g. [Sure lock demo link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock)). Can somebody explain this KitKat-compatibility?

Can somebody name a new way to hide the navigation and status bar in KitKat-releases with root priviledges?

Comment: For API-11+, I finally got happy with https://github.com/jszczygiel/AndroidKioskMode but it could not be the case for you. Hope this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you can give a try with the below code snippet to show/hide status bar on rooted android devices.I'v tested this on 4.2.2 , 4.4.2 with success.Good luck :)

To hide:

```
        Process proc = null;

        String ProcID = "79"; //HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            ProcID = "42"; //ICS AND NEWER
        }

        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "service call activity "+ProcID+" s16 com.android.systemui" });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (1).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (2).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

To show:

```
        Process proc = null;
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService" });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (1).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (2).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the `service call activity %ProcID% s16 com.android.systemui` command a little bit? I'm confused why the process id has changed from Honeycomb to IceCreamSandwich…

Comment: Could you at least name the source of your answer so that I can forward new answer (the syntax of the `service call …` command) to the original poster?

Comment: @Greeny : The process id for the SystemUI class changed from 79 to 42 when ICS was introduced hence the use of if condition to satisfy the different versions.You can also take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454528/hide-system-bar-in-jelly-bean-tablet-rooted .Good luck,happy to answer more and thanks for the bounty :-)

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly on a Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 running 4.42