# Enable Disable System UI on AOSP Build programmatically

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source, kiosk-mode

I have built my AOSP custom ROM using Android 4.4.4 sources. I want to do a kiosk mode app (always full screen - impossible for the user to leave it or to switch to another app).

In order to have a full immersive mode, I followed this SO post [Enabling KioskMode in Android 4.4.2 with Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363132/enabling-kioskmode-in-android-4-4-2-with-root)

I dit exactly as they say but it's not working. System UI is not disabled and I have no error.

So I decided to create a .sh file that I run from Android SDK code:

`Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/etc/stop-ui.sh" });`

It works perfectly. But when I want to start the System UI again :
`Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/etc/start-ui.sh" });`
 it returns error 1.

When I run /etc/start-ui.sh from adb shell it works.

Here is my stop.sh (with permission 555) file :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

Here is my start.sh (with permission 555) file :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
```

My app is a system app (I signed it with the platform signature)

Conclusion: I can restart system UI from shell but not from app programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this 2 methods (on rooted phone) and they worked perfectly:

```
public static void hideSystemUi(){
    try {
        Build.VERSION_CODES vc = new Build.VERSION_CODES();
        Build.VERSION vr = new Build.VERSION();
        String ProcID = "79"; //HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

        //v.RELEASE  //4.0.3
        if(vr.SDK_INT >= vc.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            ProcID = "42"; //ICS AND NEWER
        }
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                "su","-c","service call activity " + ProcID + " s16 com.android.systemui"});

        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void showSystemUi(){
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try to pass user id in `am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService` command. In my case it's `0` (root user id).

Comment: Wow thanks it works with adding `--user 0`. This is weird. Why isn't working without it? On many other SO posts people don't have the `--user 0` option and it works. Thanks BTW, you helped me a lot.

Comment: First method works, but second doesn't. It was not easy to return `systemUI` even manually :(

Comment: If i run 
   service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui the systemUi disappears but also the devices doesnt take any input anymore. am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService