# Android 4.4 Locked Task Mode

Tags: android, flutter

I'm creating a flutter app that will be installed on a Samsung Galaxy 7-inch Tablet with Android KitKat (v4.4). It will be the only app on the tablet, and will be implemented such that it loads when the device is powered up, and the user will be unable to exit the application.

I've found this on the Android Developer docs, but it only applies for versions 5.0 and over.
https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#java

I have not been able to find any documentation/tutorials that could possibly assist with this, without using a 3rd party application such as [Surelock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock&showAllReviews=true) and [Kioware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsi.kioware.client.mobile.app).

Is there a way to implement the above for older Android version (in my case for version 4.4)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are targeting an older Android version you will need to implement some workarounds, but luckily there is a very extensive tutorial on how to do just that for Android 4 which you can find here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20201101145703/https://www.andreasschrade.com/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

As this is very platform specific you will need to develop directly for Android and then connect it to your Dart code with [this tutorial.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

If you control the devices your software will be installed on, you can also opt for the 'root' way of doing things which is described here:
[Enabling KioskMode in Android 4.4.2 with Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363132/enabling-kioskmode-in-android-4-4-2-with-root)